# OS X: strange -psn command line parameter when launched from Finder

Tags: macos, command-line-arguments, finder

Our OS X Java application which is launched by a shell script inside the `MyApp.app` bundle gets a strange command line parameter `-psn_0_989382` when launched from the Finder, but not when launched directly from the Terminal. Where can I find information what this command line parameter is good for?

Comment: It also happens if you launch app via the `open` command. Interesting, that since 10.11 (or earlier?) this argument is only passed to the process on first launch.

Comment: I wonder why they chose to use a command line parameter for this, instead of an environment variable. Well, they might have had their reasons.

Comment: I experience this today and behavior is uncertain. I launched from Finder and observed MacOS _sometimes_ passes `-psn` and not always. I found it's very weird and uncertain behavior of MacOS.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Mac OS X assigns a unique process serial number ("PSN") to all apps launched via GUI. It's used for identifying various processes and instances of executables.

There's nothing I can really add to the documentation, so the best thing is to read the [ProcessSerialNumber section of the Carbon Process Manager Reference](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/prmref_main/data_type_5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000208/C001951) (original Apple link is dead; this is a mirror).

Comment: Though I haven't tested it, I'm not surprised. It was bound to happen someday, as Apple has deprecated all of Carbon. (Since 2008 I think?)

Comment: @ToFi Still happens today on MacOS 10.13.

Comment: Today, on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5, this -psn_ parameter is not normally passed to an app, except the first time when you get the "App downloaded from the internet" warning, and you click the Open button.

Comment: BTW this answer and the docs don't really mention why the magic parameter is passed or it's format.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that older applications that used the Carbon API get started with this argument. If the application was already updated to a version not using Carbon any more, you can unregister the application from the LaunchServices database by:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -u /Applications/AppName.app/
```

After this it can be re-launched from Finder to register the new version. Then it should not get this argument any more.